# Ubuntu updated packages list

Tags: ubuntu, update, ubuntu-10.04

Where I can find site/rss preferably which published information about Ubuntu (10.04) updated packages? I would like to be notified each time the new update is being released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to sign up for the ["Lucid-changes"](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/Lucid-changes) mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

You could alternatively install `apticron` on the machine, and it will email you with update notifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the RSS feed at http://feeds.ubuntu-nl.org/LucidChanges to subscribe to changes to all support ubuntu releases use http://feeds.ubuntu-nl.org/UbuntuStableChanges